# how to create rule for java comments in pmd?

Tags: java, pmd

Could someone please help me to create rule in pmd for eclipse? I am unable to start even i followed through PMD official site. I am planning to create rule in java instead of XPath rule. Any simple guidelines to start it? 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried following the tutorial? http://pmd.sourceforge.net/howtowritearule.html

Comment: s i followed, but still i m unable to choose which is the better way to create a rule i.e.. 'Write a rule using Java' or 
'Write an XPath expression'. Which is the easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'Write a rule using Java' method as you can easily start this way and later you can try with XPath expressions. You can follow these steps alongside the official [link](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/howtowritearule.html).

- Start with the src package that comes with PMD (e.g. pmd-4.2.x\src), create your java class inside an existing package (e.g. pmd-4.2.5\src\net\sourceforge\pmd\rules\basic). In this case it is the following sample code (WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule) :

```
    package net.sourceforge.pmd.rules.basic;

    import net.sourceforge.pmd.*;
    import net.sourceforge.pmd.ast.*;

    public class WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule extends AbstractRule {
        public Object visit(ASTWhileStatement node, Object data) {
            SimpleNode firstStmt = (SimpleNode)node.jjtGetChild(1);
            if (!hasBlockAsFirstChild(firstStmt)) {
                addViolation(data, node);
            }
            return super.visit(node,data);
        }
        private boolean hasBlockAsFirstChild(SimpleNode node) {
            return (node.jjtGetNumChildren() != 0 && (node.jjtGetChild(0) instanceof ASTBlock));
        }
    }
```

- Append the following rule inside basic.xml(pmd-4.2.5\rulesets\basic.xml) :

  Copy paste the xml content from "Put the WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule rule in a ruleset file" section to basic.xml.

  Replace the line

  ```
  class="WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule">
  ```

  with

  ```
  class="net.sourceforge.pmd.rules.basic.WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule">
  ```

  as you must have created the java file (WhileLoopsMustUseBracesRule.java) inside package "net.sourceforge.pmd.rules.basic"
- Run this command from cmd prompt if in windows.

```
    pmd.bat C:\JAVAFILE_ON_WHICH_YOU_WANT_TO_RUN_THIS_RULE xml C:\PMD\pmd-4.2.5\pmd-4.2.5\rulesets\basic.xml
```

- For the nix os (linux/MacOS), use pmd.sh instead of pmd.bat
- Once you are able to get it running, you can create your own rule inside your own package.

Hope this helps.!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial a while back with some sample code that could be helpful.

http://www.techtraits.ca/writting-pretty-code-with-pmd/